# How to populate FXCollections.observableArrayList with loop? [javafx]

Tags: java, list, javafx

This is part of my code

```
for (Object o : materia2) {
    String v = o.toString();
    datos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Tabla(v));
}
```

where through a list (List  materia2) to convert each element of that list in string, later, full FXCollections.observableArrayList (new Table (v)); where "v" is every string converted, but only the last item in the list is sponds, my question is, as I do so that each element of the list appears correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Create the list once, and add an element to it each time you iterate through the loop:

```
datos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for (Object o : materia2) {
    String v = o.toString();
    datos.add(new Tabla(v) );
}
```